# windows phone 8.1 tile color to a specific color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, tile

I am using the queue mechanism of tiles in Windows phone 8.1 and i am wondering if it possible to set the tile color to a custom color and not the default theme chosen by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Package.appxmanifest` file look for `<m3:VisualElements>` and set `BackgroundColor="red"` or whatever color you wish. This is your app's personal color.  Your Live Tiles will inherit this color.